# AS3/AIR Save/Load multiple usernames using SharedObject

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, save

I am trying to create an Android application created using Adobe Flash Actionscript 3. I wanted each user of the app to input their name in the beginning of the application, then they have the capability to save their progress in current frame (and it will be saved into a save slot or similar). However, the problem arises when another user is going to use the app, he/she must enter a distinct username, and he/she can save anytime (and load his/her distinct load progress, different from the previous user.). And it goes on.

I am a newbie in programming and I hope you could help me. Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks!

This my code for creating a username and saving it:

```
function handleClick(Event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var myFirstVariable = boxOne.text;
    boxTwo.text = myFirstVariable;
    gotoAndStop("opening_scene")
}
myButton2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, handleClick);
```

UPDATED EDIT 2: Here is my code for saving and loading. Still not working:

```
var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("Test");
var userName:String = nameField.text;

if (so.data.users == null)
    so.data.users = new Object();

btnSave.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (so.data.users[userName] == null)
    so.data.users[userName] = new Object();
    so.data.users[userName].lastframe = currentFrame;
    so.flush();
    trace(userName);
}

btnLoad.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, reloadBtnClick);
function reloadBtnClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (so.data.users[userName] == null)return;
    if (so.data.users[userName].lastFrame == null) return;
    gotoAndStop(so.data.users[userName].lastFrame);
    trace(userName);
}
```

Comment: Well, if you can't do databases, you need to have a username stuffed into the savefile together with their frame. meaning you need another layer of object over `mySharedObject.data` that's user dependent.

Comment: @Vesper could you give me a example code? Thanks

Comment: `mySharedObject.data.users[i].currentframe`, where `i` should be user dependent and stored somewhere when you load.

Comment: @Vesper I am bit lost, I am sorry I am a newbie. Could you provide a sample code with two or more users? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use a SQLite Data Base to save your data can find all the documentation here [Manipulating SQL database data](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7d27.html) Well is a little bit more complicate but works like have tables in Excel.

Comment: You should try and will be better for future projects.

Answer (score 0):

As Vesper suggested, you need to have a storage with all the users you store. For example:

```
// Put user name here.
var userName:String;

var SO:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("save");

// Create storage for users.
if (SO.data.users == null) SO.data.users = new Object();

// ...

function saveCurrentFrame(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    // Create storage for current user by their name.
    if (SO.data.users[userName] == null) SO.data.users[userName] = new Object();

    SO.data.users[userName].lastframe = currentFrame;
    SO.flush();
}

function getLastFrame(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace(1);
    // Skip this if there's no record for 
    if (SO.data.users[userName] == null) return;
    trace(2);
    if (SO.data.users[userName].lastFrame == null) return;
    trace(3);

    gotoAndStop(SO.data.users[userName].lastFrame);
    trace(4);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I am getting there though I still have some questions. First, in your code, where I could insert the part where the instance name of the username input txtbox (for example boxOne) could be inserted? Secondly, is it possible to have an "identical" username or will it have an error? Lastly, is it possible to have a list of "saved slots" that contains the usernames and timestamps when it was saved? Again, thank you so much!

Comment: You can replace userName with your boxOne.text if it is available everywhere, or save its text to the variable. Identical usernames are identical and will be treated as one user. Yes, you can read all the saved names with > for (aName:String in SO.data.users)

Comment: will it look like this var userName:String = boxOne.text?

Comment: Is it possible for the saved names to be treated like buttons? and is it possible for it to appear like scroll box with saved names in it that can be loaded anytime?

Comment: Sure. Create a visual object (MovieClip/Sprite) that represent one user, like a button with user name on it. Make it accept username in its constructor. Then use the loop I gave you above to create these buttons for each saved user. Vary their Y-coordinate so they form a column.

Comment: I am overwhelmed, I can't catch up as I am a newbie. Assuming that the button I will create has the instance name of  mc_userBox, how can I accept its username as its constructor? Can you please give me an example code where you utilize the loop you have given me, with variations in their Y-coordinate? Also, how I can limit them so that they will scrollable?, instead of filling the whole app with buttons? I appreciate your help so much!

Comment: Let us be slow and steady: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b8ea63-7fee.html

Comment: Think of Library as of blueprint collection. Once you have a blueprint in your Library, labelled and indexed (read: exported for ActionScript), you can create as many objects according the given blueprint as you want. At any time.

Comment: Thank you, I am currently studying the link you have given me. However, how could I make them "scrollable" when there are many users who registered their name who are using the app?

Comment: Don't be so hasty please. The first milestone is to make a column of these objects, all of them.

Comment: Hello sir, after I made column of these objects, what's next? Thanks!

Comment: Use ScrollPane component: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/components/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7fa2.html

Comment: is it possible to create my own customized graphics for scrollbar? Because the built in scrollpane component is not suitable to the theme of my android application. Thanks!

Comment: Please see my updated code(still not working) in my question content. Thanks!

Comment: It works for the first user who input his name and saves his progress. However, the moment I close the app, it doesn't load the last saved scene. I also type his name and press the load button, but still not working. It also fail to load saved progress by different users (with different usernames).

Comment: Method trace(...) allows you to output various debug info. Put trace(userName) into the functions where you load/save progress. It must output the user name for whole thing to work properly. If it does not... then, we'll see.

Comment: I tried to implement trace method but it's not working (no trace output is displaying as I click the load/save button). The load button is not functioning well. Kindly check the newly updated and edited code in my question. The main premise of my problem is the ability to load/save the currentframe with respect to the distinction of usernames. I am planning of instead of having a scrollbar that loads the names of users, I will instead have 3 save/load slots, that displays the username and the time it was saved. Please help me, I need to finish this before January 29, thanks alot!

Comment: I put some edit into your code. Run it and explain the results.